# Htaccess on Nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

I have one Question. **How can I use my Htaccess File on nginx?**

I have seen something like that: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

But I don't know if this is working and where should I put the Codes in?

**Can someone help it would be awesome!**

Greetings Slaxxer

Answer (score 1):

NGINX doesn't have support for anything like .htaccess (Unless I'm mistaken) so you'll need to put the rules into an NGINX config file, probably within a virtual host.

A virtual host is the specific configuration for a domain, within the NGINX config it will look like

```
  server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
  }
```

(Taken from the NGINX sample config)
So you would put your converted .htaccess rules within the location{} square brackets (Equivalent to Apache's ).
To give a full example, say I have some URL rewrites in my .htaccess file

```
#Enable URL Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite some pages
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).html$ /pagehander.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Running it through the converter I get

```
rewrite ^/page/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).html$ /pagehander.php?page=$1;
```

So I would put that in my NGINX server config like

```
  server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

    location / {
rewrite ^/page/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).html$ /pagehander.php?page=$1;
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you mean Virtual Host? Another guy told me also that but I don't understand it..

Comment: @Slaxxer Edited the post to give a bit more info.